# How can I print a joined table of strings in Lua?

Tags: lua

Okay I am working on a script for my Oxide Lua Plugin, and I am also just learning Lua Script so I am not real sure how to do this.

```
-- *******************************************
-- Broadcasts a Server Notification 
-- *******************************************
function PLUGIN:cmdNotice( netuser, args )
  table.concat(args," ")
  local allnetusers = rust.GetAllNetUsers()
  if (allnetusers) then
    for i=1, #allnetusers do
      local netuser = allnetusers[i]
      rust.Notice(netuser, args[1]))
      rust.SendChatToUser(netuser, "Message Sent:" .. args[1])
    end
  end
end
```

What I am trying to do is fix this so I do not have to manually encase my notice in "".

For example, as the code stands, while I am in game in rust if I use the `/notice` command I have two outcomes.

Example 1

```
/notice hello everone
```

will only produce

```
hello
```

but if I do

```
/notice "hello everyone"
```

will give the entire message. So I am a little confused.

So my new code should look like this

```
-- *******************************************
-- Broadcasts a Server Notification
-- *******************************************
function PLUGIN:cmdNotice( netuser, args )
  table.concat(args," ")
  local allnetusers = rust.GetAllNetUsers()

  if (allnetusers) then
    for i=1, #allnetusers do
      local netuser = allnetusers[i]
      rust.Notice(netuser, table.concat(args, " " ))
      rust.SendChatToUser(netuser, "Message Sent:" .. table.concat(args, " "))
    end
  end
end
```

Edit 3/15/2014

Okay cool so in a since I can also do this as well correct?

```
function PLUGIN:cmdNotice( netuser, args )

    if (not args[1]) then
        rust.Notice( netuser, "Syntax: /notice Message" )
        return
    end
  local allnetusers = rust.GetAllNetUsers()
  if allnetusers then
    for i=1, #allnetusers do
      local netuser = allnetusers[i]
      local notice_msg = table.concat(args," ")
      rust.Notice(netuser, notice_msg)
      rust.SendChatToUser(netuser, "Message Sent:" .. notice_msg)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Save the concatenation in variable `local whole_msg = table.concat(args," ")` and then use `whole_msg` instead of `args[1]`

Comment: Your code was missing some closing parentheses and had a few too many `ends`. I cleaned that up, but see my answer below for a longer response about your revised code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify what @EgorSkriptunoff said, `table.concat` returns the joined table, but it does not change the value of `args`. Since you don't save the joined return value, your line 1 inside the function is useless. As an alternative to his approach, you could do `rust.SendChatToUser ( netuser, "Message Sent:" .. table.concat(args, " " )`.

My guess is that you were thinking (?) that the joined strings would be saved in the `args` table as the first item in the table? That's not what happens. The table itself remains unchanged, so when you print `args[1]`, you get only the first string of the array. It "works" when you quote the message because in that case the entire message goes in as one thing, and the array only has an `arg[1]`.

Here's what is going on

```
t = { "hello", "I", "must", "be", "going"}

-- Useless use of concat since I don't save the return value or use it
table.concat(t, " ")

print(t) -- Still an unjoined table
print(t[1]) -- Prints only "hello"

print(table.concat(t, " ")) -- Now prints the return value
```

**Edit**: In response to the follow-up question, see my comments in the code below:

```
function PLUGIN:cmdNotice( netuser, args )
  table.concat(args," ") -- This line is not needed.
  local allnetusers = rust.GetAllNetUsers()

  -- Lua doesn't count 0 as false, so the line below probably doesn't do
  -- what you think it does. If you want to test whether a table has more
  -- than 0 items in it, use this:
  -- if #allnetusers > 0 then...
  if allnetusers then
    for i=1, #allnetusers do
      local netuser = allnetusers[i]
      rust.Notice(netuser, table.concat(args, " " ))
      rust.SendChatToUser(netuser, "Message Sent:" .. table.concat(args, " "))
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Cool I have edited my question with the final code i have thus far and it is working flawlessly in game now thanks to your help